# Would it be appropriate to use JDesktopPane and JInternalFrame in this instance?

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing a program that currently switches back and forth between different JPanels placed on a JFrame that also has a JMenuBar. (We're required to use Swing.)

I need to write a tutorial and right now I have it giving step-by-step instructions from a popup window. However, it doesn't seem to resonate well with test users and quite frankly it's annoying to switch back and forth between screens.

After checking out JDesktopPane and JInternalFrame it seems to make sense to place my entire program in a desktop pane and then create the tutorial using an internal frame. I'm worried that this will force me to place my different screens each in an internal frame which is NOT what I want to do. I just want the tutorial to be an internal popup(?) that can be minimized and moved around if necessary.

Am I going about this the correct way or is there a more efficient/practical way to implement the same tutorial popup feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on your problem -- is it that your tutorial keeps popping up new windows for each step? I would assume that you wish both the main program and the tutorial to both be in view while the tutorial is running, and if this is so, perhaps the tutorial should reside in a non-modal JDialog, and then you swap tutorial screens via a CardLayout. ... unless I'm mis-reading your requirements and problem.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm looking for, thank you. However, the group I'm working with wants something a little more "special" so I may have to go with an internalFrame just because it looks a little different.